# Writing in the form of "One of XXX (plural)" in GF

Tags: gf

I'm trying to generate the sentence **One of my friends** on GF using the GF library.
I failed at finding the right method for constructing a prep after a numeral and on creating the relation of **one of** with the **plural** noun.

[image]

as the class of `Noun Phrase` shows, `Numeral` or `Digits` only have `Common Noun` or `Noun` after them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### CountNP

There is a function for this in the [Noun](https://github.com/GrammaticalFramework/gf-rgl/blob/master/src/abstract/Noun.gf#L151) module, but unfortunately it's not in the RGL API. The function is `CountNP`:

```hs
CountNP : Det -> NP -> NP ;    -- three of them, some of the boys
```

To use it in your grammar, you need to open the module NounEng. The usual practice is to open non-API modules qualified: instead of `open NounEng in { … }`, we give it a shorthand, like N: `open (N=NounEng) in { … }`. Then in the body of the grammar, you need to write `N.CountNP`. Here's an example, you can copy and paste it into a file called `Friend.gf`.

```hs
resource Friend = open SyntaxEng, LexiconEng, (N=NounEng) in {
  oper
    one_Det : Det = mkDet (mkNumeral n1_Unit) ;

    my_friends_NP : NP = mkNP (mkDet i_Pron pluralNum) friend_N ;

    friend : NP = N.CountNP one_Det my_friends_NP ;
}
```

#### Predet

Other times when you want to modify an already existing NP, you can use the [Predet](http://www.grammaticalframework.org/lib/doc/synopsis/index.html#Predet) category. Here are examples (you can paste them into the same file Friend.gf).

```hs
-- The RGL includes some Predets, like all, most and only:
all_friends : NP = mkNP all_Predet my_friends_NP ;
most_friends : NP = mkNP most_Predet my_friends_NP ;
only_friends : NP = mkNP only_Predet my_friends_NP ;
```